# Method in one class can't find the variable in another

Tags: java

In the class "CheckingAccount.java" I am trying to use the following:

```
public String accountNumber(){
    String date = Account.date;
    String name = Customer.name;

    String account = date + ", " + name;
    return account;
}
```

Which makes use of a method in the class Account.java

```
public String date(Locale currentLocale){
    DateFormat df;
    df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, currentLocale);
    String formattedDate = df.format(getDateOpened());

    String date = "Opened: " + formattedDate;

    return date;
}
```

and the class Customer.java

```
public String name(){
    String name = "Name: " + getName();
    return name;
}
```

However, the method in CheckingAccount.java can't see Account.date or Customer.name and I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT:** OK, to be clear, I am NOT trying to call the method. I am trying to call the variable within the method. I also do NOT want to create new objects here. The objects will have been created in another class and will just need to be able to access the variables at that time.

Comment: Learn about static variables and methods and how to use them.

Comment: Well, for one it seems you're confusing methods and variables. `Account.name` would be a static (not a good idea) variable called `name` in class `Account`, whereas `Account.name();` would be a static method call (again, not a good idea here). A good tutorial is what you need.

Comment: my concern you should learn basic of java then do coding

Comment: @Elliander so you want to access a variable that is not only invisible but does not even exist in memory (because the method is not called)?

Comment: There's something missing, that makes this question unanswerable (other than "you can't access local variable inside the method because of scoping"): Does your `CheckingAccount.java` has `Account` and `Customer` instance (e.g. `Account account;` declared somewhere)? Because if not, then it's impossible to get that (and there's a bigger issue).

Comment: You can't access the variable within the method. The scope of that variable means that it does not exist outside of the method. The concept of encapsulation means that you shouldn't even need to know how the method works or what the code is inside it, because you should be calling the method itself. I know you don't want to call the method, because I read your question, but that's how Java works.

Comment: @Elliander **you can't "call" a variable**. You can access it if it's within your scope, and **a variable declared in the body of another method is *never* in your scope**. You want *attributes*, for starters. This is basic but extremely important information, please *do* read an introductory textbook where it is neatly laid out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` and `date` are instance methods - you need an instance of `Account` and `Customer` in order to access them, i.e.:

```
public String accountNumber() {
    String date = new Account().date();
    String name = new Customer().name();

    String account = date + ", " + name;
    return account;
}
```

However it seems more like you're trying to use them in a static fashion, which means they have to be static (common to all occurrences of `Account` and `Customer`), meaning:

```
public static String date(Locale currentLocale) {
    DateFormat df;
    df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, currentLocale);
    String formattedDate = df.format(getDateOpened());

    String date = "Opened: " + formattedDate;

    return date;
}

public static String name() {
    String name = "Name: " + getName();
    return name;
}
```

However note that in this case any variable or method they are trying to access must be static as well. Without more clarification as to your usecase, I cannot tell which of these manner you should employ.

Comment: Frankly, this is only slightly better than the original code.

Comment: Actually, no. I will be creating new objects in another class so I really can't create new objects here or that will cause a serious problem. I will look into a static approach though.

Comment: @Henry I don't have the luxury of choosing how I set up my methods here. I'm not allowed to deviate here.

Comment: In the meantime, you made it method calls (which again makes it a bit better) but you still miss the argument for the `date(Locale currentLocale)` call

Comment: Again, I do NOT want to call the method! I want to call the variable within the method! String name and String date!

Comment: Also:  If I was trying to call the method Customer().date() would be incorrect. It would just be Customer.date(). The problem with trying Account.date(Locale currentLocale is that it would be able to find Locale.

Comment: @Elliander: people here are usually willing to help. There is a reason if SO is among the top resources (if not *the* top resource along with `man` and the various language specs) for engineers and developers. However, you question does not make any sense whatsoever (as in: you confuse methods with attributes with local variables, classes with instances, basically everything with everything else), so it's **perfectly understandable that people point this out to you so that you can work on it**. I think you should be grateful instead of stomping your feet and calling troll.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer** to your question is,

The variables which are inside a method cannot be accessed any where outside that method.

To clarify your doubts let me help you understand a bit about Variables in Java.

Basically you can have three types of variables.

1. Instance Variables
2. Class Variables
3. Local Variables

**Instance Variables** are the ones that are declared at class level (outside the methods) and they can only be used by the Object/Instance of that class.

For Example,

```
class A{
    int a; // this a variable is an instance variable.
}
```

To use this variable in any other class you need to do something like,

```
A obj = new A();
obj.a = 10;
```

Point to be noted here is each object of the class will have its own copy of instance variable.

**Class variables** are the ones that are declared at class level but with `static` keyword.

For example,

```
class A{
    static int b;
}
```

This `b` variable will be the class variable and it can be used directly by class name.

```
A.b = 10;
```

There is no need to create object to access this variable. Class variables are not associated with objects. Instead they are common for all objects.

**Local Variables** are the variables that are declared inside any method or any other block.

Their scope is within the `{ }` where they are declared and can never be used outside that block.

For example,

```
class A{
    public void hello(){
        int a; //local variable
        // it can be used here
    }

    // but it cannot be used outside the method
}
```

Now coming to your question. You said

> EDIT: OK, to be clear, I am NOT trying to call the method. I am trying to call the variable within the method.

The variables `name` and `date` are the local variables in their corresponding methods. Therefore they cannot be accessed the way you are trying to do.

Instead you need to create object of your class and then call its methods

```
public String accountNumber() {
    Account account = new Account();
    String date = account.date();
    String name = account.name();

    String account = date + ", " + name;
    return account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not how you call methods in Java, you have to add parenthesis after the method name to indicate that you are calling a method.
In addition Customer.getName() wouldn't work as this is an instance method of Customer. you need to create an instance of the Customer class in order to call it.
You can do the following (assuming Customer has a default constructor):

```
new Customer().name()
```

The new keyword tells java you are trying to make a new instance of the given class, in this case Customer. With that instance you can then make a call to the name method.

Comment: I'm not trying to call the method. I'm trying to call the variable within the method. I also do NOT want a new object here.

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to put instance for Account class and then invoking data().same u    should follow for customer class.

public String accountNumber()
{    
  Account account=new Account();
  Customer customer=new Customer();

String date = account.date();
String name = customer.name();

String account = date + ", " + name;
return account;
}
OR you can directly calling method by creating object.like
public String accountNumber() {
String date = new Account().date();
String name = new Customer().name();

String account = date + ", " + name;
return account;
}
```